# InvalidProgramException en archivo .IL (Intermediate Language de Microsoft)

Tags: .net, cil

Este es el código

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly UsingTheArgs {}

.method static public void main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack 1

  ldstr "Hi my name is {0}"

  ldarg.0
  ldc.i4.0
  ldelem.ref

  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
  ret
}
```

Y me genera una `System.InvalidProgramException`, me dice:

> Common Language Runtime detectó un programa no válido en main()

¿A qué se puede deber esto? Estoy aprendiendo MSIL y este es uno de mis primeros ejemplos que pruebo y la verdad es que no tengo ni idea de por qué no puede andar.

Comment: porque estas aprendiendo MSIL ? no se programa en este lenguaje, deberias programar en C# y al compilarlo se gener el MSIL.

Comment: Porque quiero aprender qué es lo que pasa cuando compilas una aplicación en C#. Me interesa únicamente con fines educativos, no me voy a dedicar a escribir en MSIL, pero me gustaría poder realizar algunos ejercicios para saber que lo que estoy entendiendo está bien, y no que estoy aprendiendo mal las cosas.

Comment: @Augusto Excelente que hayas encontrado... En vez de editar la pregunta, lo mejor sería que lo publiques como respuesta y la aceptes

Comment: @Mariano Ah perfecto, gracias por aclarar. En seguida lo cambio

Comment: Genial! Gracias por contribuir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución. No estaban en orden los valores en la stack al momento de llamar al método `System.Console.WriteLine`, se pasaba primero un `object` y después un `string`, en vez de un `string` y luego un `object`. Cree dos variables locales y con esas variables locales puse en orden los parámetros.
Les dejo el código correcto para que se vea cuales eran los errores:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly MyFirstSample {}

.method static public void main(class System.String[]) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack 2
  .locals init (string message,
                string argument)

  ldstr "Hi my name is {0}"
  stloc message

  ldarg.0
  ldc.i4.0
  ldelem.ref
  stloc argument

  ldloc message
  ldloc argument

  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
  ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No creo que IL este tan pensado para aprenderse, es ams dudo que haya manuales para aprenderlo, quizas si se use como medio para analizar

Podrias usar tools como ser

http://ilspy.net/

en donde aplica un disasembler de .exe o dll para pode analizarlo tanto en IL como en codigo .net

podrias crear tu programa en c#, aplicar ILSpy y comparar con el codigo que estas creando para ver que diferencias notas y asi deducir que te esta faltando

Creo que esa es una buena tecnica para aprender, escribir codigo en un lenguaje conocido como es C# y ver que IL genera

Comment: Si, tengo dos herramientas, una es ILSpy y otra .Net Reflector, el problema con esas herramientas es que el código que generan a veces es muy complejo para entenderlo. Por eso me baje un curso y con el curso estoy viendo algo desde lo básico. Igualmente averiguando un poco encontré unos libros y ya me voy a poner a leerlos. Muchas gracias igual. Relacionado a la pregunta, ¿alguna idea de porque puede estar pasando esa excepción?

Comment: pero si creas algo basico que sea de consola, cuando aplicas un disassembler podrias comparar con el codigo que estas escribiendo y ver que falte. La verdad es que no conozco sobre IL, y dudo que alguien se ponga aprenderlo